# Alternatives for SVN Post commit hooks

Tags: svn

Requirement : run a custom script after every commit to SVN repo. repo used by 10 people. so, after a commit by anyone, need to run the script.

Existing Solutions

1. Post commit hook - there is no hooks folder and I cant create since I am not the administrator.
2. Hudson, cruise control - overkill, since I am not looking to setup continuous deployment or such fancy stuff.
3. SVNNotify, CommitMonitor - will not run any script on commit, just will send out email on commit.

Are there any other solution which will satisfy my requirement ?

Environment : linux, rhel

Comment: If you can't install a hook, then you have no choice but to poll.  This could be as simple as writing a cronjob.

Comment: I am planning to run it on my desktop, so dont wanted to poll every few minutes, if there are no options then I could ultimately end up polling. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Hudson, cruise control - overkill, since I am not looking to setup continuous deployment or such fancy stuff.

I use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) which is a fork from Hudson (or maybe Hudson is a fork off of Jenkins now since Kohsuke Kawaguchi who created Hudson now works for Jenkins).

Jenkins may seem to be overkill, but it's pretty darn simple to setup and get working:

- Install Java (a JDK distribution is preferred, but it runs fine with just a Java Runtime Engine).
- Run `java -jar jenkins.jar` from the command line

And, that's pretty much it. The whole process takes less than five minutes. Defining a job to run your script will take another five minutes. In under 15 minutes, you'll have everything working perfectly. If you never used Jenkins or Hudson before, give yourself another 10 minutes to figure it out. No matter what else you do will take longer to setup.

The only downside to using Jenkins is that once you have Jenkins installed, you'll probably be asked to do more and more with it, and since you're the one who installed it, it will be your job.